# How can I simplify this mysql query, based on 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, join, sum, coalesce

after 2 days of trial and error, I just completed this mysql query. It works fine, but it does look really hideous. Is it possible to simplify my query ? All help is of course greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 

    p.*,     
    COUNT(oT.Ontmoeting_ID) + COUNT(oU.Ontmoeting_ID) AS 'played',     
    COUNT(case oT.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_FF when 1 then 1 else case oT.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_Bonus when 3 then 1 else null end end)    
    + COUNT(case oU.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_FF when 1 then 1 else case oU.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_Bonus when 3 then 1 else null end end)    
    - COUNT(case oU.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_FF when 1 then case oU.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_FF when 1 then 1 else null end end)    
    - COUNT(case oT.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_FF when 1 then case oT.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_FF when 1 then 1 else null end end) AS 'won',    
    COUNT(case oT.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_Bonus when 1 then 1 else null end) + 
    COUNT(case oU.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_Bonus when 1 then 1 else null end) AS 'draw',    
    COUNT(case oU.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_FF when 1 then 1 else case oU.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_Bonus when 0 then 1 else null end end)    
    + COUNT(case oT.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_FF when 1 then 1 else case oT.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_Bonus when 0 then 1 else null end end) AS 'lost',    
    SUM(COALESCE(oT.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_Totaal, 0)) + SUM(COALESCE(oU.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_Totaal, 0)) AS 'Totaal'
    FROM ploegen AS p    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ontmoetingen AS oT ON oT.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_ID = p.Ploeg_ID AND oT.Ontmoeting_Competitie_ID = 1 and oT.Ontmoeting_Speelweek <= 2 AND (oT.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_Totaal > 0 OR oT.Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_FF = 1)    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ontmoetingen AS oU ON oU.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_ID = p.Ploeg_ID and oU.Ontmoeting_Competitie_ID = 1 AND oU.Ontmoeting_Speelweek <= 2 AND (oU.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_Totaal > 0 OR oU.Ontmoeting_Uitploeg_FF = 1)WHERE p.Ploeg_ID IN (select Ontmoeting_Thuisploeg_ID from ontmoetingen WHERE Ontmoeting_Competitie_ID = 1)    
   GROUP BY p.Ploeg_ID    
   ORDER BY totaal DESC
```

The query is based on 2 tables, "ontmoetingen" and "ploegen" (in English: "encounters" and "teams"). It calculates the overall standings of the teams, adding all played, won and draw encounters. The main difficulty is that all teams play both home and away games and those have to be summarized ("Thuisploeg" = "Home Team", "Uitploeg" = "Away Team". Please let me know if more info on the tables is required to help me out. Thx !

Table: "Ontmoetingen":

[image: Table: "Ontmoetingen":]

Table: "ploegen":

[image]

Expected output:
[image]

All numbers in output are fictional, so not corresponding to table data. Hope this helps !

Comment: Please reformat your question to make it readable.

Comment: could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: *"SQL-92 and earlier does **not** permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or **ORDER BY** list refer to **nonaggregated columns** that are **not named in the GROUP BY clause**"* See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) about `GROUP BY` which looks like you are using it wrong unless MySQL could have used a SQL:1999 standard optional feature which is called [functionally dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) which we can't verify without `CREATE TABLE` statements..

Comment: I edited the question, added the tables and output.